# Sending messages from lightning component to visualforce component

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

I am trying to send messages to visualforce component from lightning component:

My lightning component:

```
<aura:component controller="CustomBuildingFormController" description="BuildingMap"
                implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:actionOverride,force:hasRecordId"
                access="global">

  <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
  <aura:attribute name="vfDomain" type="String" default=""/>
  <aura:attribute name="isDoneRendering" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
  <aura:handler event="aura:doneRendering" action="{!c.doneRendering}"/>

  <!-- The Visualforce page to send data to -->
  <div style="overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto;">
    <iframe aura:id="vfFrame" scrolling="no" src="{!v.vfDomain + '/apex/buildingMapIframe'}" style="border: 0px none;
                     margin-left: 0px; height: 700px; margin-top: -70px; width: 100%;">
    </iframe>
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

My Lightning component controller:

```
({

    doInit: function (component, event, helper) {

    },

    doneRendering: function(component, event, helper) {
        if(!component.get("v.isDoneRendering")){
            component.set("v.isDoneRendering", true);

            var message = {
                x: '',
                y: '',
                name: ''
            };

            var getRecordData = component.get("c.getRecordById");
            getRecordData.setParams({recordId: component.get("v.recordId")});
            getRecordData.setCallback(this, function (response) {
                if (response.getState() === 'SUCCESS'){
                    message.x = response.getReturnValue().x__c;
                    message.y = response.getReturnValue().y__c;
                    message.name = response.getReturnValue().Name;
                }
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(getRecordData);

            // Custom settings
            var action = component.get("c.getCustomSettings");
            action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
                if (response.getState() === 'SUCCESS'){
                    component.set("v.vfDomain", response.getReturnValue());
                    var vfOrigin = response.getReturnValue();
                    var vfWindow = component.find("vfFrame").getElement().contentWindow;
                    vfWindow.postMessage(message, "*");
                } else {
                    return response;
                }
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);

        }
    }

});
```

And my visualforce component:

```
<apex:component id="buildingMapComponent">

  <input type="hidden" id="lexOrigin" value="{!$Setup.DomainURL__c.Lightning__c}"/>
  <script type="text/javascript"></script>
  <div class="slds-form-element slds-size_1-of-2">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="InAadressDiv">Address Search</label>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control" id="InAadressDiv" style="z-index: 1">
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    var fields = {};

    window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
      var lexOrigin = document.getElementById("lexOrigin").value;
      if (event.origin !== lexOrigin) {
        // Not the expected origin: reject message!
        console.log("error!")
        return;
      }
      console.log("success")
      // Handle message
      fields = event.data;
    }, false);
```

To me, it seems, that visualforce page is not catching my message that i am sending. The domain url's are valid, i have checked them at least 5 times. I am sending messages from visualforce to lightning componet too, and it works like charm.

**If I send the message to my correct visualforce domain, i get error in console:
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('VISUALFORCE DOMAIN') does not match the recipient window's origin ('LIGHTNING DOMAIN').**

Also tried to broadcast the message: **"*"** as target origin. Still same result, VF is not catching the message.

Any ideas why my visualforce is not reciving message? As You can see i have console logged some messages in my eventListener, neither **error** or **success** gets logged.

Comment: For those who are curious, this code comes from [this article](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/01/lightning-visualforce-communication.html).

Comment: @sfdcfox yes, i am following the article, but from LC to VF its not working. Other way its working, from VF to LC.

Comment: I found https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication which seems to go super in depth on this topic. The common issue I found when digging around on the internet is that the iframe may not be fully loaded by the time the message is posted. I'm not sure if this is your issue though.

Comment: @gNerb i was concerned about this. Thats why i am doing my postMessage action in `doneRendereing` function. doneRendering fires when dom is fully loaded.. So i don't think that there is the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure that's true. I'd imagine that it finishes when the lightning component dom is fully loaded but I'm hesitant to think that it also waits for the iframe.

Comment: @RSICK, you can go the other way round and post message from VF back to lightning and in response to that post message to VF that way you know VF is loaded

Comment: @RedDevil thank you,  that seems a trick that might do it. Going to try it.

Comment: I solved the problem, the problem was in the rendering sequence. Iframe was not fully rendered when lightning components rendering was done. So i solved to problem by sending dummy message from VF to LC and then in callback i sent the data from LC to VF, which is what i wanted. It works, because if i can send message from VF to LC, i can surely know, that Iframe is rendered.

Comment: @RSICK , can you would you be ok to share the piece of code that says vf is fully loaded and then postmessage can be done ?

Comment: @user2945545 What you do: Add an event listener to your LC, which listens for message lets say 'loaded'. In your VF component, you do window.onload() function, where you postmessage to your LC with body 'loaded'. When your VF is loaded, it sends out a message, LC will recieve the message. Now we can be sure, that VF is loaded, and you can send your postmessage from LC.

Comment: Basically, first we are making handshake between VF and LC, and then we can communicate.

Comment: yep i figured out yesterday and achieved it ,great though , thanks for it!! @RSICK